# Spring Security Config Https issue

Tags: java, spring, https

I am new with Spring. I have an issue regarding configuration to allow https redirection after login. I am using Vmware vfabric tc server as a web server.

In `app-security-context.xml` I have a warning in http block. 
This warning is:

```
Referenced bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.
ChannelDecisionManagerImpl' not found 
[config set: PresentationLayer/ web-context]
```

So when I try to login an error message appears in my browser "The page is not available"

Comment: Post the contents of your `app-security-context.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem comes from that warning (it's just a warning). When you deploy the app, don't you see any error trace?

Anyway, you can remove that warning by adding a few lines in your security context. For example:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
    <property name="channelProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.InsecureChannelProcessor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```